# How to determine HOA rights for roof replacement

Tags: illinois, hoa

I live in a collection of townhouses (about 100) with an HOA. Certain blocks of townhouses share a roof, but they are fee simple and homeowners are legally responsible for their roofs, although the management company has hired roofers for general spot checks.

Due to leaking problems in some of the townhouses, the HOA undertook a survey (with 50% or so reponses) and has now come up with a plan to do a major roof replacement which (after one quote) will cost in the order of $4.5 million, or $45K per unit (for townhouses with pretty small roofs). While this may not be the final plan, the management company claims that the HOA has the full legal authority to decide on such a plan by themselves. I can't seem to find anything in the bylaws which gives them such an authority. But then, I'm not sure where to look exactly. Thus my problem:

> How do I determine (from the bylaws of the HOA or otherwise) what authority they have in making decisions with significant one off costs for owners? (And what votes if any are required by residents) What language should I be looking for in the HOA?

If it matters, this is in Illinois, USA.